# MySQL Insert else delete stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a toggle system that will allow users to add items to a collection. They can then remove the items which removes the row from the database. This is easily done using 2 queries, but i wanted to replace this with a stored procedure to save having to do this using 2 queries. What i want to do is check if a row exists, if it does delete it, if not insert it.

I am using phpmyadmin and i am trying to create a routine. I have added 2 (itemid, use parameters that are set to "IN"

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid) THEN 
    BEGIN 
        DELETE FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid
    END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO useritems (ItemID, UserID) VALUES(itemid, userid)
    END;
END IF;
```

When i try to submit it i get the following error

```
MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END;
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO useritems (ItemID, UserID) VALUES(ite' at line 4
```

Comment: `END` should not have a semi-colon, but your statements (the queries) should.

Comment: Did you change your delimiter before defining the stored procedure?

Comment: i didnt change anything im trying to paste this in using the routine tab for the database. i didnt modify anything in advance of doing this

Comment: [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) - There is no `BEGIN` and `END` in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right syntax for `IF` statement in `MySQL`:

> `IF search_condition THEN statement_list
>       [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
>       [ELSE statement_list]
>   END IF`

Refere to [MySQL Dev Site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

So fix your code to be like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid) THEN 

    DELETE FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO useritems (ItemID, UserID) VALUES(itemid, userid);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (SELECT * FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid) 
THEN
         DELETE FROM useritems WHERE ItemID = itemid AND UserID = userid
ELSE 
         INSERT INTO useritems (ItemID, UserID) VALUES(itemid, userid)
END IF;
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answers. Just dumping SQL isn't helping anyone and is frowned upon. Please revise this and your other answers. Thanks!